# convert nullptr to std::optional

Tags: c++, option-type, nullptr

I have a library defining `method()` that returns type `V*` and can return `nullptr`. What's the best way to wrap that method to turn the value into a `std::optional<V>`?

The naive way would be something like:

```
std::optional<V> maybe_value;
V* value = method();
if (value != nullptr) {
    maybe_value = *value;    // assuming the type is even copyable
}
```

But I was hoping there'd already be some STL function I could use to do this as a one-liner wrapper around `method()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your way looks basically fine to me, and is roughly what I'd do. You don't *want* a one-liner here as it would not be very clear. Ultimately you can create a function for it if you like.

One concern: be very careful with ownership semantics here. Who owns `*value`? Can it be copied? Is that meaningful? Can you move it instead? Who frees the original object?

Always ask these questions when passed a pointer, even if it appeared that the pointer was only chosen in order to add nullability.

To be quite honest, although `std::optional` is preferable in new code (or code you're refactoring), I'm not convinced that *wrapping* a function like this is worth the potential confusion, not to mention the cost of a copy (if, indeed, that is necessary).

Comment: In fact your way is exactly what I do, including the `maybe_` prefix ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such function. Assignment of any value makes the optional containing a value. But you can provide your own

```
template <typename T>
std::optional<T*> optional_ptr(T* ptr) {
    return ptr ? std::optional<T*>(ptr) : std::optional<T*>();
}
```